# get percentage when using graphviz and d3 to generate pie DAG

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, graphviz

When writing the dot file, I set the node shape as circle and fill two colors to generate pie DAG. The problem is I want to use tooltips to show the data percentage. Is there an easy way to achieve that? Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://viz-js.com/bower_components/viz.js/viz-lite.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.0.4/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>

<script>

var dotIndex = 0;
var svgContainer = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("id","dag")
                     .attr("width", 300)
                     .attr("height", 900);
var pieDagContainer = svgContainer.append("g").attr("id","pieDagContainer");
var graphviz = pieDagContainer.graphviz();

function render() {
    var dotLines = dots[dotIndex];
    var dot = dotLines.join('');
    var transition1 = d3.transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(500)
      .transition()
        .duration(1500);

    graphviz
        .dot(dot)
        .transition(transition1)
        .render();
}
var dots = [
    [
        'digraph  ""{',
        'subgraph clusterstage_0 {',
        '    label="Stage 0"',
        '    node [shape=circle, style="wedged"]',
        '    a0 [fillcolor="yellow;0.8:orange"]',
        '    a1 [fillcolor="yellow;0.8:orange"]',
        '    a2 [fillcolor="yellow;0.5:orange"]',
        '    a3 [fillcolor="yellow;0.2:orange"]',
        '    a0->a1->a2->a3',
        '}',
        '}'
    ],
];


render();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) attribute [tooltip](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dtooltip) on the nodes like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://viz-js.com/bower_components/viz.js/viz-lite.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.0.4/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>

<script>

var dotIndex = 0;
var svgContainer = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("id","dag")
                     .attr("width", 300)
                     .attr("height", 900);
var pieDagContainer = svgContainer.append("g").attr("id","pieDagContainer");
var graphviz = pieDagContainer.graphviz();

function render() {
    var dotLines = dots[dotIndex];
    var dot = dotLines.join('');
    var transition1 = d3.transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(500)
      .transition()
        .duration(1500);

    graphviz
        .dot(dot)
        .transition(transition1)
        .render();
}
var dots = [
    [
        'digraph  ""{',
        'subgraph clusterstage_0 {',
        '    label="Stage 0"',
        '    node [shape=circle, style="wedged"]',
        '    a0 [fillcolor="yellow;0.8:orange" tooltip="80%"]',
        '    a1 [fillcolor="yellow;0.8:orange" tooltip="80%"]',
        '    a2 [fillcolor="yellow;0.5:orange" tooltip="50%"]',
        '    a3 [fillcolor="yellow;0.2:orange" tooltip="20%"]',
        '    a0->a1->a2->a3',
        '}',
        '}'
    ],
];


render();

</script>
```

Comment: Thank a lot! It is really helpful.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)